# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring Boot to develop a community website, when I try to test the "registration" function it shows this error:

```html
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Aug 16 01:02:01 EDT 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
    at com.nowcoder.community.service.UserService.register(UserService.java:48)
    at com.nowcoder.community.controller.LoginController.register(LoginController.java:26)
```

As it mentions the line 48 staring from "if(StringUtils.isBlank(user.getUsername())) "

```html
public Map<String, Object> register(User user) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        // Empty value
        if (user == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User cannot be null!");
        }
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(user.getUsername())) {
            map.put("usernameMsg", "Username cannot be empty!");
            return map;
        }
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(user.getPassword())) {
            map.put("passwordMsg", "Password cannot be empty!");
            return map;
        }
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(user.getEmail())) {
            map.put("emailMsg", "Email cannot be empty!");
            return map;
        }
```

I have added commons-lang3 in the pom.xml

```html
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I'm using IntelliJ, not sure if it's related.
I have imported the import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Check Java Build Path of the JAR.

If you are deploying it and running it on a server try to put the JAR file in the \lib subfolder of the Apache Tomcat installation.

Comment: I think it's already there, I just checked the lib contains "commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar"

Answer (score 0):

i think you may import this package
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

Comment: Probably a good idea as that will probably save an extra dependency. Mystifying why this is functionality is not in the JRE (afaik)

Comment: I tried and it shows "'org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils' is already defined in a single-type import"

Comment: Remove that import and replace with `import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;`

Comment: then if (StringUtils.isBlank(user.getUsername())) "isBlank" turns to red and report error

Comment: Try changing `isBlank` to `isEmpty`